# Finding a convex function between two points

Tags: functions

Given two points of the $xy$ plane, is there a way to find the equation of a convex function between those two points? I know the answer wont be unique so I'm just looking for a general equation that would work

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? Clearly, the line connecting the two points or a convex quadratic function works. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: And please specify what you mean by "function between those two points".

Comment: Ambiguity exists in this question. Two types of solutions exists here. One can FIND a convex function existing as a path joining the two points in the plane (as any convex, real-valued function is sufficiently continuous) -- e.g., a linear, a quadratic (as Yves Daoust generalizes below), an exponential, etc. function that initiates at one point, and monotonically increases to the other point is a convex function whose equation is a solution. Secondly, mvw's solution below parameterizes the convex combination of the two points in the plane, and is the general equation of said line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parabola
$$y(x)=y_0+(x-x_0)\left(\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}+x-x_1\right).$$

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Comment: Although I'm commenting on an old post (apologies), I up-voted your solution as it is a solution (see my comment to OP above).

Answer (score 5):

Given points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ on the plane,

$$\frac{y_2-y}{x_2-x} = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

is the formula of the straight line that goes through both of them and can be rewritten as

$$y = (x-x_2)\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} + y_2$$Is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, a convex combination of the points $u_1$ and $u_2$ ($u_i \in \mathbb{R}^2$) is $\lambda_1 u_1 + \lambda_2 u_2$ with $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1$ and $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

You can derive the parameterization
$$
u(\lambda) = (1-\lambda) u_1 + \lambda u_2 \quad (\lambda \in [0,1])
$$
from this. In coordinates you get:
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x \\
y
\end{matrix}
\right)
(\lambda)
=
(1-\lambda)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
y_1
\end{matrix}
\right)
+   
\lambda 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_2 \\
y_2
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Comment: You can downvote him or ask for closing (he didn't provide the requested clarification).